# stackoverflow for empty function

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

Look at this code :

```
void f()
{
    f();
}
```

I know that because so many `f()` ​​functions are called, StackOverflow occurs.
But my question is what is exactly stored in the stack that causes this error, return address for each `f()` function call?
Because this function has no variables, so why does StackOverflow occur?

Comment: Why not compile it and step through the assembler to see? But yes, if there are no local variables or arguments it'll be the return address and possibly a copy of the stack pointer called the frame pointer. This may depend on the specific CPU and OS you're using. If your compiler does tail-call optimisation it might not overflow.

Comment: How do you know that it results in a stackoverflow? It might not.

Comment: You can have a look into the assembly code.

Comment: be aware that your question is about implementation details. C++ code is not instructions for your CPU, but an abstract description of what the program is supposed to do. Your function does nothing infinite times. A priori there is no reason to expect an overflow.

Comment: I recommend that you take some time to study common hardware architectures and how functions calls are handled on the lowest level. Knowing what happens "under the hood" help you become a better programmer in languages like C and C++ (and really any language that exposes pointers).

Comment: @Scheff the flaw of my point is that an infinite loop without sideeffects is UB, so its not just implementation details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other answers already said, it's because of the return addresses.

```
void f(){
  f();
}
```

compiles to

```
f:
  call f #Let's assume f has the address 0x1000 for later purposes
  ret
```

But what does `call` do?
It does two things:

1. Push the current address to the stack
2. Call the specified address.
   It's essentially:

```
f:
  push %rip
  jmp 0x1000
  ret
```

If you "unroll" this calls you have:

```
f:
  push %rip
  push %rip
  push %rip
  push %rip
  push %rip
  push %rip
  ....
```

And so on. As you can see, you always push an address to the stack. This works until you hit other areas and overwrite them. (This illustration assumes an architecture with a backwards-growing stack, like x86)

```
[heap].......[stack pointer][stack] #Start
[heap]......[stack pointer][stack ] push %rip
[heap].....[stack pointer][stack  ] push %rip
[heap]....[stack pointer][stack   ] push %rip
[heap]...[stack pointer][stack    ] push %rip
[heap]..[stack pointer][stack     ] push %rip
[heap].[stack pointer][stack      ] push %rip
[heap][stack pointer][stack       ] push %rip
[heap[stack pointer][stack        ]# Boom, you for example reached the heap and you are overwriting it.
```

Answer (score 5):

For every function called the stack stores its return address, in order to resume execution at the next instruction when the function returns. This is the [*call stack*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

Comment: You mean this error occurs because of the large number of return addresses stored?

Comment: Yes. See here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Comment: @mahsa Compilers can store extra data as well, besides the return address. You really have to check the generated assembly code to see what it stores.